# If I link to clean URLs based on the page title but redirect to URLS with ids as part of a site migration, is that bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting, url-parameters, clean-urls

I'm importing stuff from a Drupal site that has a couple of alias URLs:

```
/node/123
/my-alias-node-title
```

My new site is a very simple CMS handmade in PHP by me as a practice.  In the new system, the URL for each page has this format:

```
/contenido.php?id=30
```

I've managed to rewrite all traffic to a PHP file (`reenvio.php`) using a rewrite rule:

My .htaccess file is like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./reenvio.php
```

My PHP file consults the database and do the redirects.
So, when users type `/node/123` they get redirected to `/contenido.php?id=30`

Is that a problem from an SEO perspective? My pages will still link to URLs like `/my-alias-node-title` but my users will end up seeing `/contenido.php?id=30`

Is there any way to address this issue in a different, better way? Because after all, the user still sees the ugly URL, so I assume Google sees it as well.

Comment: You are redirecting to URLs with question marks in them.  That is changing your URLs for users and search engines.  So I think the marked duplicate is appropriate, no?

Comment: Not exactly, because the other question was about what is better for search engines (if I did understand it correctly). My question is if a simple redirection is enough for the url to be considered clean, because the link that appears in the page, after all, is /whatever, so I guess that it will be follower by a search engine, even if it end up being a dirty one...

Comment: I think I am finally understanding.   I've edited your question based on our conversation.  Feel free to fix anything I got wrong, but I think it is clear it is a different unique question now, and it should be answerable.

Comment: Much clearer! Thanks Stephen! I'm argentinian, so, sometimes I get lost in translation :)